# How to use localstorage to send data into another html file(NOT SPA) - angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am not using SPA app, so if i click another html file the page loads, so i cant catch the data, i want to store in that localstorage.

This is my controller file:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.users = [{
                name: 'sameer',
                age: 21
            },
            {
                name: 'ganesh',
                age: 22
            }
        ]

        $scope.setcontactModal = function(user) {
            $scope.modalcontactData = user;
       }
   });
```

My first index page:

```
<body ng-controller='myController'>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Operations</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='user in users'>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.age}}</td>
            <td> <a href="edit.html" ng-click='setcontactModal(user)'> Apply </a> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I want to share this $scope.modalcontactData into another file called edit.html file:

This is my another html file called **edit.html**

```
<body ng-controller='myController'>
        <p>hello {{modalcontactData}} </p>
</body>
```

I tried this:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngStorage'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope,$localStorage) {

        $scope.users = [{
            name: 'sameer',
            age: 21
        }, {
            name: 'ganesh',
            age: 22
        }]

        $localStorage.modalcontactData = $scope.modalcontactData;

        $scope.setcontactModal = function(user) {
            $scope.modalcontactData = user;
            console.log('scope:', $scope.modalcontactData);
         }
    });
```

Comment: a query string might be better.

Comment: Can you show what you’ve tried so far? The use of local storage in Angular is pretty well documented, surely you’ve at least tried what you’ve found online already.

Comment: I tried ngStorage dependency, and tried $localStorage stil i did not get the data. it hide when the page loads

Comment: Post the code where you actually use LocalStorage.

Comment: see my updated question @TsvetanGanev

Comment: `$localStorage.modalcontactData = $scope.modalcontactData;` this line should be inside the `setcontactModal` function.

Comment: I put inside also not working.

Comment: Open Chrome DevTools (F11 -> Application -> Local Storage)  and see if the value is stored successfully there. I didn't see where are you getting the value after it has been stored. Can you post the `edit` controller?

Comment: Both pages are same controller called "myController"

Comment: Im getting localstorage data inside chrome dev tools, but not showing on page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use local storage like this.

working demo:https://plnkr.co/edit/84V6v7qkeE62hI1eU0eu

```js
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngStorage'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.modalcontactData=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user"))
        $scope.users = [{
            name: 'sameer',
            age: 21
        }, {
            name: 'ganesh',
            age: 22
        }]
      

        $scope.setcontactModal = function(user) {
            $scope.modalcontactData = user;             window.localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log('scope:', $scope.modalcontactData);
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the data in local storage you can use local forage its a very helpful library for storing and retrieving data in json format.

Just add this file to your index.html https://github.com/localForage/localForage/blob/master/dist/localforage.js

```
<script src="js/localforage.js"></script>
```

And now you can easily store or retrieve data from local storage in json format using these simple functions.To save the data you can use-

```
localforage.setItem("modelContactData", user);
```

And to retrieve the data use-

```
localforage.getItem("modelContactData",function(err,data){
     console.log(data);
});
```